# Update Program Name - Multi Million Records

Tags: sql, database, performance, sql-update, database-performance

I need to update 5 million rows in the account table.

```
update account set name = 'NEW PROGRAM NAME' where progid = 1111;
```

However, regular update was running and running for 1.5 hours. I had to cancel it and then it took time to cancel. It was a mess.

I need the expert advice on how to update quickly and in as less time as possible.

I prefer 1 script. But I was thinking may be:

```
update account set name = 'NEW PROGRAM NAME' where progid = 1111 and rownum <= 500000;
```

And then commit ?

Answer (score 0):

You are very close:

```
update account
    set name = 'NEW PROGRAM NAME'
    where progid = 1111 and name <> 'NEW PROGRAM NAME' and
          rownum <= 5000;
```

You can repeatedly do this update, with commits in between.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please add the index for the field progid.
2. Add one more condition to filter records where name <> 'NEW PROGRAM NAME'
3. I do not recommend you update 5 million rows by one script. You should update 5000 records per batch to avoid row locks.
4. If the database design can be change, you should perform database normalization. Create a table 'program' to store the progid and name, the table 'account' only store the field progid, so that you just update one of the record in table 'program'

   ```
   While (Select Count(1) From account Where progid = 1111 and name <> 'NEW PROGRAM NAME') > 0
   Begin
   update account
   set name = 'NEW PROGRAM NAME'
   where progid = 1111 and name <> 'NEW PROGRAM NAME' and
     rownum <= 5000; 
   End
   ```